# Exception using getCalculatedValue() in phpExcel

Tags: phpexcel

these are the exception I am getting:

I am getting the following exception:

Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Cyclic Reference in Formula'

I am dealing with a excel sheet which contain very complex calculations. I can not write them all here. I am using an interface to send the values to specific cells of that excel sheet. and then getting back the calculated value from the output cells.

use of getOldCalculatedValue() gets the correct values first Time I use it (I have no idea how)

The problem with getOldCalculatedValue() is that this is not the solution. also when i update my input values , output value does not change.

now i checked deeply.. these are the formulas which are generating exceptions:

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'STEAM!B30 -> STEAM!E57 -> STEAM!B56 -> STEAM!B38 -> STEAM!B89 -> internal error'

B30:=IF(G32=1,IF(E570,D55<>0),IF(G32=1,IF(E57

E57: ==IF(B44

B56:=B38*SQRT(IF(E44=1,B52,1^(3/4)*B53^(1/4)*B52/E43^(3/4)/E44^(1/4))/E43)

B38: =VLOOKUP(B70,CHART,2)

B89: ==HLOOKUP($E$4,WLC2CV,VLOOKUP($B$4,WLC2CV,15))

and there is warning generated, when i am handling the exception by assigning it old calculated values.

Warning (2): sqrt() expects parameter 1 to be double, string given [APP\vendors\Classes\PHPExcel\Calculation.php, line 3324]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A cyclic formula is one like (for example) cell A1 contains the formula =B1+1 while cell B1 contains =A1+1, ie. where executing the formula results in a chain of calculations that loops back on itself

This can be valid in Excel, though the default behaviour is to generate an error message when it is encountered. However, you can change this behaviour so that Excel will process the formula through a specified number of cycles or iterations.

PHPExcel supports both behaviours: the default is to generate the error message, as Excel does. But if you set the calculations engine's $cyclicFormulaCount property to a value greater than 0, it will emulate the second behaviour that Excel can exhibit.
At it's simplest level

```
PHPExcel_Calculation::getInstance()->cyclicFormulaCount = 1
```

will suppress cyclic errors and allow a basic cyclic calculation to be executed, setting $cyclicFormulaCount to higher values will allow the formulae to be calculated through several cycles or iterations (to the value that you specify).

The getOldCalculatedValue() method retrieves the result of a calculation as last executed by MS Excel itself. This may be correct, but is not guaranteed (eg if formula calculation has been suppressed in excel itself).

Comment: I have tried that count value but it does not work. I have figured out that... the calculated values i m getting from sheets are #value!, #ref!, #num! etc. but same cells which are generating these error are displaying correct values in excel sheet for same inputs. and all the formulas are suppressed in excel sheet. I have used debug log to dump history as u hv suggested but all the browsers are crashing while displaying the output log. Now I am in middle of nowhere.

Comment: Try using the command line script for debugging spreadsheet formulae rather than a browser... and increase memory. The debug log will almost certainly tell you exactly where the problem lies, but the logger does need to run to completion to give a full picture.